# Hide Cursor in Text Input of Numeric Stepper on Mouse Roll Out in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

How can I hide cursor in the text input field of Numeric Stepper on Mouse Roll Out Event in Flex?

Comment: You want hide IBEAM cursor and keep opportunity change text with keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Works with flex4

```
<s:NumericStepper x="370" y="102" mouseOut="stage.focus=null"/>
```